# Debug.WriteLine shows up only in Output window and not Console window

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, console, console.writeline

I am trying to clear up what gets written in the console when not debugging so for example when running in release it will not show up. So for that i use this method for the Logging that should not be shown

```
    public static void DebugWriteConsole(string s)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss | ") + s);
        if (Log.logger != null)
        {
            Log.Info(s);
        }
    }
```

And it works in that regard that it doesn't show up when running in release but the problem i have is that i run the application with `-c` so it runs in a console window but when running in debug the `Debug.WritLine` only prints into the vs output window and nothing in the console window. Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has been explained in the Microsoft Docs in the [TraceListeners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.listeners?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Debug_Listeners) collection topic

You can use TextWriterTraceListener and specify the System.Console.Out as the stream where you want to write (or any other suitable stream instance)

```
TextWriterTraceListener myWriter = new TextWriterTraceListener(System.Console.Out);
Debug.Listeners.Add(myWriter);
```

or just use ConsoleTraceListener.

```
ConsoleTraceListener trc = new ConsoleTraceListener();
Debug.Listeners.Add(trc);
```

Another option is to use a pragma directive to overcome the NET Core problem

```
public static void DebugWriteConsole(string s)
{
    #if DEBUG
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss | ") + s);
    #endif
    Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss | ") + s);
    if (Log.logger != null)
    {
        Log.Info(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: I will mark your answer as right as it is the right way with .Net but my problem was that .Net Core doesn't have Debug.Listeners so i will also write what made mine work

Comment: Well, the .NET Core problem was unexpected. I have added another option using the [#if preprocessor directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) to add printing, in case of debug, directly to the console with the classic Console.WriteLine.

Comment: yeah i forgot to mention that but thank you for the information

Answer (score 1):

Steve way will probably work for most but if you are using `.Net Core` and have this problem i found a solution like this since .Net Core doesn't have `Debug.Listeners` A way to do this is by writing the method likes this

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public static void DebugWriteConsole(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss | ") + s);
        if (Log.logger != null)
        {
            Log.Info(s);
        }
    }
```

still using the `Console.WriteLine` but putting the `Conditional` attribute on the method

Comment: I don't think that this is what the OP wants. The Conditional("DEBUG") will force the compiler to remove all calls to the method when the DEBUG symbol is not defined. But, of course, the log part should continue to work in Release mode.